# Validation for either of the fields are non-empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Suppose I have two text fields and I need to validate for either of the fields are non-empty.

I have tried like

```
"vImage": {
    "myfunction_valid": function(){
                 if(('#vimg1').val()) return true;
                 else if($('#vimg2').val()) return true; 
                 else return false; 
          }
        }
```

But it is not working. Can anyone suggest me the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the code shown is part of an object literal, and there could be other problems in the code you haven't shown, but in what you *have* shown you've got a syntax error on the line with the `if`:

```
if(('#vimg1').val()) return true;
```

Should be:

```
if($('#vimg1').val()) return true;
```

For further help you will need to show us more of your code. How do you call that function? What is the rest of the object that `vImage` belongs to?

> *"Can anyone suggest me the better way"*

Well you could simplify the function to this:

```
"vImage": {
    "myfunction_valid": function(){
          return $('#vimg1').val() != "" || $('#vimg2').val() != "";
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is typo.Sorry for that

Comment: Yes, I saw that you updated your question, but it still has a typo - you added the missing `(` but it is still missing a `$`.

Comment: Excellent..Working fine now.I also tried with it but I have put without `!= ''`.Thanks

Comment: I included `!=""` so that my suggested short version would still return an actual boolean and not just a truthy or falsy value. If truthy or falsy is acceptable you can say `return $('#vimg1').val()  || $('#vimg2').val();`